# Managing multiple layers at once

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers

I'm new to GIS. I currently have two lots of data that I'm working with: a shapefile map, and land cover data courtesy of the ONS. What I need to do is lay the shapefile map over the land cover map so I can draw an additional area around my existing shapefile map (another software I'm using requires them to be a certain size).

I'm sure there's a simple fix for this, but I can't figure out where I should even start with it. I've tried importing both datasets separately, but as soon as I import the second one, the first disappears. As I said, I'm a beginner so I really have no idea how setting the CRS or anything like that works.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your datasets are correct when it comes to specifying their CRSs, they should align on the map canvas in QGIS (QGIS will take care of transformations).

One possibility is that your second dataset hides the first one. If you set the second dataset to transparent (right-click on the layer in the *Layers panel*, choose *Properties...* (at the bottom of the context menu), go to the *Symbology* tab, scroll down to *Layer Rendering*, and move the *Opacity* slider to the left).

You could also move the second dataset below the first one in the Layers panel (click, drag and release), to see if that makes the first one visible.

If this does not help, you probably have a CRS problem with the datasets.